# Check value is a passed variable before allowing form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a variable passed through in a function to check against an input of a form and prevent submission if not matched. I am new to javascript and jQuery.

This is what I have at the moment stripped back to the basics. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
  <form id="timer" name="octo-ans" method="post">
      <input id="octo-ans-box" type="text" placeholder="answer" name="answerRoom<?php echo $RmNo; ?>" />
      <input id="octo-room-submit" type="submit" onSubmit="checkAnswer(<?php echo $answer; ?>)" value="Send" name="octo-send" />
  </form>
```

```
function checkAnswer(answer) {
            if ($("#octo-ans-box").val().toLowerCase() === answer) { // have tried == and ====
                return true;
            } else {
                $("#octo-timer").delay(500).animate({ backgroundColor: "#F00"}, 100 ).animate({ backgroundColor: "#000"}, 1000 );
                return false;
            }
        }
```

However the form seems to submit itself everytime without matching  the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing single quote:

Correct:

```
<input id="octo-room-submit" type="submit" onSubmit="checkAnswer('<?php echo $answer; ?>)" value="Send" name="octo-send" />
```

(This way your `$answer` is getting passed as a javascript variable/reserved keyword where as it is a string).

To

```
 <input id="octo-room-submit" type="submit" onSubmit="checkAnswer('<?php echo $answer; ?>')" value="Send" name="octo-send" />
```

Comment: Hi Pupil, I have corrected my code accordingly but still seems to end up submitting form - sorry

Comment: I have also tried the above with what Adil has suggested below by adding the return to the beginning of the function name

Comment: Try `obsubmit` on `<form>` instead of button. It must work.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for you help - I have it working by adding `return` making `onSubmit="return checkAnswer('<?php echo $answer; ?>')"` on the form. The background color animations isn't working at the moment but at least the form doesn't submit. Thanks!